# generating GIF thumbnail for video - flutter - image

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing, animated-gif

i'm trying to create an animated thumbnail for videos on the device. Its an android/ios flutter app.
so my approach was to do it on the phone with the following dart packages:

```
  flutter_video_compress: ^0.3.7+8
  image: ^2.1.13
```

the code below isn't the full code, the .convertVideoToGif (flutter_video_compress) works well. However the generated GIF file is big, so i used the image package to downsize and cut number of frames. But the generated GIF from the Image package always generates a GIF file with red artifacting, anyone has any idea why its doing that?

The sample gif file generated:
https://cdn.tracorder.com/videos/3tIbEYH_1601602948035.mp4.gif

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as pic;
import 'package:flutter_video_compress/flutter_video_compress.dart';

{
    thumb = await _flutterVideoCompress.convertVideoToGif(
            videoPath,
            startTime: 0, // default(0)
            duration: 3, // default(-1)
            endTime: -1 // default(-1)
          );
    
    
          debugPrint("Thumb : " + thumb.path);
    
    
          pic.Animation thumbTemp = pic.decodeGifAnimation(thumb.readAsBytesSync());
          int frameDividor = (thumbTemp.length/5).round();
          pic.GifEncoder gifEnc = new pic.GifEncoder(delay: 50, repeat: 0, samplingFactor: 100);
          pic.Image tmpImage;
    
          for(int t=0; t < thumbTemp.length; t++){
    
            if((t % frameDividor) == 0){
              tmpImage = pic.copyResize(thumbTemp.frames[t], width: 250);
              gifEnc.addFrame(tmpImage, duration: 30);
    
            }
    
          }
          thumbAnime = pic.decodeGifAnimation(gifEnc.finish());
    

          thumb.writeAsBytesSync(pic.encodeGifAnimation(thumbAnime));
}
```

---

> Edit:

---

Ended up using flutter_ffmpeg, here's what i ended up using:

```
  var arguments = ["-i", videoPath, "-ss", "00:00:01","-t","00:00:03","-vf","fps=3,scale=120:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse", "-loop","0",thumb.path];
  _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments).then((rc) {
        print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc");
        setState(() {
          _thumbReady = true;
        });
    }
  );
```

Comment: I had same problem did u make it?

Comment: hey, eventually i just used the flutter_ffmpeg package to generate the gif, think it made the apk kinda big, but it works

Comment: well... i saw package info it seems pretty hard for me

Comment: can u share the code ?? dev.silenmus@gmail.com

Comment: hey, i added above, it just creates a gif file

Comment: thanks made it appreciate it 

Comment: SILENMUS, if you have a different solution. let me know.. ffmpeg adds quite a bit of size to apk build.. hehe

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to compile some important details regarding video/gif/image compression issues in Flutter, it's not always clear what is and isn't supported on Android **AND IOS**. Don't expect older packages to age well, so be mindful about what packages you end up using :)

---

Package [flutter_video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress) :

- Has not been updated since 6/3/2019
- Loses file.path location when using newer file "Picker" tools
- GIF's don't work on IOS, and the package itself doesn't compile for IOS anymore

---

Package [video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress/install):

- [video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress/install) can do everything  [flutter_video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress)  can do, minus the GIF's (but development is coming soon). So I recommend planning on using [video_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress/install) moving forward.
- Very fast compression
- 50MB video can be compressed to 5-7mb with 720p quality in about 4-8 seconds

---

Package [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

- 0.7.0 compiles in IOS and Android as of 1/22/2021
- Very fast and efficient
- Updated as of July 2020
- Can't do Gifs, but for all other image compression it's great

---

Package [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg):

- Very large APK size after importing
- Overkill for most use cases
- Starting to get old if updates don't happen soon (last update was Sept. 2020 as of today)

As you stated the [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) code can be used like this to generate a gif:

```
 var arguments = ["-i", videoPath, "-ss", "00:00:01","-t","00:00:03","-vf","fps=3,scale=120:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse", "-loop","0",thumb.path];
  _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments).then((rc) {
        print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc");
        setState(() {
          _thumbReady = true;
        });
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Any new thoughts/approaches on GIF compression.
Would prefer not to use ffmpeg due to bundle size concerns.
Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you ever find a good alternative, was thinking maybe creating a fake gif by using thumbnails from different video positions... they really need to update video_compress to support gifs. I can't believe it hasn't been done already